# Complicated array join in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm having an array like this:

```
pairs = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']]
```

I'd like to join them and create a new array so that on the output I'd have something like this:

```
['a_b', 'b_c', 'c_d']
['g_h', 'h_j', 'j_k', 'k_l', 'l_m']
```

I'm struggling with an algorithm and can't come up with something. How can I do that?

Comment: For each element `n` in a list, pair it with its next element `n + 1` (if `n + 1` exists) and add the result to a list. Do this for all lists individually, creating several pair lists. Combine resulting pair lists into a single list. Sound like what you want?

Comment: Look at all the ways you can do that! :D

Comment: @ThorSummoner Yeah, I'm kind of overwhelmed with all the possibilities! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[['{}_{}'.format(*x) for x in zip(p, p[1:])] for p in pairs]
```

1. the `for p in pairs` part iterate each of your input lists.
2. `zip(p, p[1:])` returns pairs of each item with the next item
3. `'{}_{}'.format(*x)` gets the string you requested

Comment: or `map('_'.join, zip(p, p[1:])`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yours is even better!

Answer (score 1):

```
joinedIt = []
for i in range(0, len(pairs)):
    for j in range(0, len(pairs[i])-1):
        joinedIt[i].append(pairs[i][j] + pairs[i][j+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> pairs = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']]
>>> [[s[i] + '_' + s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1)] for s in pairs]
[['a_b', 'b_c', 'c_d'], ['g_h', 'h_j', 'j_k', 'k_l', 'l_m']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using for loops with ranges

```
def parse(list):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(list) - 1):
        new_list.append(list[i] + "_" + list[i+1])
    return new_list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
zipped =  (zip(x,x[1:]) for x in pairs)
[["{}_{}".format(ele[0], ele[1]) for ele in x ]for x in zipped]
```